# Clickable hyperlink in QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I want to use `QTextEdit` (in read-only mode) to show a clickable hyperlink, I used to do

```
QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
QTextCursor cursor(textEdit->document());
textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
cursor->insertHtml("<a href=\"www.google.com\" >Google</a>");
textEdit->show();
```

this code will show Google as hyperlink but unable to click.
And if I used

```
QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
QTextCursor cursor(textEdit->document());
textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
QTextCharFormat linkFormat = cursor.charFormat();
linkFormat.setAnchor(true);
linkFormat.setAnchorHref("http://www.google.com");
linkFormat.setAnchorName("Google");
cursor.insertText("Google", linkFormat);
```

then nothing happen. "Google" is just normal text.

Please help me insert clickable hyperlink to `QTextEdit`.

Answer (score 14):

To have clickable hyperlink in QTextEdit, you can use

1. [`QTextCharFormat::setAnchorHref`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcharformat.html#setAnchorHref) to set the link for some text
2. [`QWidget::mousePressEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) to capture mouse press event
3. [`QTextEdit::anchorAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#anchorAt) to obtain the link

Here's the minimal working PyQt example,

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QDesktopServices, QUrl, QApplication, QColor, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit


class MyWidget(QTextEdit):

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.anchor = self.anchorAt(e.pos())
        if self.anchor:
            QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        if self.anchor:
            QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl(self.anchor))
            QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            self.anchor = None


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
editor = MyWidget()
cursor = editor.textCursor()
fmt = cursor.charFormat()
fmt.setForeground(QColor('blue'))
address = 'http://example.com'
fmt.setAnchor(True)
fmt.setAnchorHref(address)
fmt.setToolTip(address)
cursor.insertText("Hello world again", fmt)
editor.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: This is the base solution I ended with. I changed it to use a mouseMoveEvent() to set the anchor and change the cursor to a PointingHand when on the anchor, and reset the cursor when not on an anchor. mousePressEvent() is not needed anymore and mouseRelease is used to open the url if the anchor is set.

Comment: Don't forget to call the super() class mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent implementations from the overriden methods, or you'll lost the standard mouse interaction with the widget!

Answer (score 13):

Using `QTextBrowser` is simpler (as suggested by another answer). However, if for some reason you want to use `QTextEdit`, try to change the text interaction flags using `setTextInteractionFlags()`.
I think you have to enable the `Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse` flag.

See [Qt::TextInteractionFlag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextInteractionFlag-enum) and [QTextEdit::textInteractionFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qtextedit.html#textInteractionFlags-prop)

Comment: Note: if you use the setTextInteractionFlag() with a QTextEdit, there's no way to detect the link was clicked. If you want to manually handle the activated link/anchor, you must use a QTextBrowser.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I've tried, when using `QTextEdit` + `Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse` I'm able to click on links, but no action is taken (i.e., link is not open). The only action possible is to right-click on the link and select `Copy Link Location`.

As mentioned, one option is using `QTextBrowser`. In this case you have to set the [`QTextBrowser::openExternalLinks`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#openExternalLinks-prop) property too, in order to open the link using the default browser, otherwise it will be open in the text-browser widget.

Another option, given you have a read-only text, is to use a `QLabel` with [rich format](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop), and using the [`QLabel::linkActivated`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#linkActivated) signal to [open the URL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl)

```
label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
QObject::connect(label, &QLabel::linkActivated, [](const QString & link) {
  QDesktopServices::openUrl(link);
});
```

Comment: Note: I found that if you are linking to a file to be opened in addition to using .setOpenExternalLinks I needed to add the URL scheme "file://" for the link to work on MacOS

Answer (score 4):

You can use QTextBrowser instead of QTextEdit if it read only text.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `setTextInteractionFlags()` to work the `openExternalLinks` property needs to be set. Since this property is not available on `QTextEdit`, here is a little hack to enable it.

```
auto &clist = edit->children();
for each (QObject *pObj in clist)
{
  QString cname = pObj->metaObject()->className();
  if (cname == "QWidgetTextControl")
    pObj->setProperty("openExternalLinks", true);
}
```

This does not address the mouse cursor, so you will still need to override `mouseMoveEvent`.