# Using links inside QTextEdit

Tags: qt, hyperlink, qtextedit

ALL,

If I have a QTextEdit with the bunch of text and will want to insert a hyperlink in this text somewhere, will I get a handling of this hyperlink for free or I will have to write some additional code to handle the hyperlink hovering/clicking?

TIA!

[EDIT]

What I mean to ask was - whether it is possible QTextEdit to recognize the hyperlink after typing www.google.com and pressing either `Space Bar` or `Enter` key, so that it becomes rendered appropriately.
I don't want my user to type `< a href=....`.

Thank you and sorry for the confusion.

[/EDIT]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clickable hyperlink in QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858340/clickable-hyperlink-in-qtextedit)

Comment: @Aleph0, and so I presume there is no auto URL detection on typing, like for example on Windows, where I type URL press space or enter and it will render the text as URL (blue and underlined)? I just tried to do this in Kate on *nix and there was no indication I typed the URL.

Comment: @Aleph0, sorry I guess I worded the question incorrectly. I will re0-write it more appropriately. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Better to have a late answer than no answer at all. I have worked on this issue to answer another question by user [@caramel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22976394/caramel) who, unfortunately, has deleted it before I could finish...  I thought I might as well not let it go to waste.

Displaying links in a `QTextEdit` is easy: use the QTextBrowser subclass. This is the answer presented in many questions on the topic; however all these questions are limited to making links behave correctly in the widget and none really address the case where users may type URLs.

There is a number of details to address, all of which makes the exercise non-trivial:

- Detecting a URL is being typed
- Adressing the case where a URL is being deleted
- Ensuring the link does not extend when pressing space/Enter to edit the next word.

### Identifying URL

The pattern presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/20143744) is the one I have chosen to use here.
This is basically the first pattern I stumbled across and I have not checked it; there could be better ones out there in case you hit some limitations.
It requires some small fixes to work in C++ (all the `\` must be turned into `\\` for the compiler) and to work during edition (the pattern must be surrounded by elements to guarantee it will not match a URL stuck to a word without a space to separate them).

```
(\\(|\\b)https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{1,256}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)(\\)|\\b)
```

### The solution

`QTextBrowser` remains the class of choice because of its `setOpenExternalLinks` method. Without that, the best you can do is copy URL to paste in the browser, rather than directly click the generated link.
With that said, `QTextBrowser` is read-only by default and we will need to address that.

In order to avoid reading the whole text contained by the control, we use a `QTextCursor` to determine the part of text currently being edited.
And because we are going to alter that (to create a link, we must replace the `linkAddress` text being typed by a markdown `[linkAddress](linkAddress)`), we need to restore the cursor position at the end of the method.

Here is a complete solution, all the logic is set up in the lambda connected to `QTextEdit::textChanged`.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QRegularExpression>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextBrowser>
#include <QtGui/QTextDocumentFragment>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QTextBrowser* te = new QTextBrowser();
    te->setReadOnly(false);
    te->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
    te->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction | Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
    //MySyntaxHighlighter* highlighter = new MySyntaxHighlighter(te);
    QRegularExpression re(
        "(\\(|\\b)https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{1,256}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)(\\)|\\b)",
        QRegularExpression::PatternOption::CaseInsensitiveOption | QRegularExpression::PatternOption::DontCaptureOption | QRegularExpression::PatternOption::InvertedGreedinessOption
    );

    QObject::connect(te, &QTextEdit::textChanged, [te, re]() {
        auto cursor = te->textCursor();
        int cachedPosition = cursor.position();
        auto testSeparator = [](char16_t character) -> bool {
            return character == ' ' || character == '\r' || character == '\n' || character == '\t' ||
                character == 8233 /*\u2029: paragraph separator*/
                ;
        };

        //Browse the text around where the edition is taking place
        char16_t character = '\0';
        if (!cursor.atStart()) {
            do {
                if (!cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousCharacter, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor))
                    break;
                character = cursor.selectedText()[0].unicode();
            } while (!testSeparator(character));

            cursor.clearSelection();
            if (testSeparator(character))
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextCharacter, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
        }

        do {
            if (!cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextCharacter, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor))
                break;
            character = cursor.selectedText().right(1)[0].unicode();
        } while (!testSeparator(character));


        //Change the text to create/remove a link if necessary
        if (auto textToAnalyze = cursor.selectedText(); re.match(textToAnalyze).hasMatch()) { //Add link if a URL is detected
            te->blockSignals(true);
            cursor.beginEditBlock();
            cursor.removeSelectedText();
            cursor.insertMarkdown(QStringLiteral("[%1](%1)").arg(textToAnalyze));
            cursor.endEditBlock();
            te->blockSignals(false);
        }
        else if (auto textMarkDown = cursor.selection().toMarkdown(); re.match(textMarkDown).hasMatch()) { //Remove link if a URL is being removed (Del / backspace key)
            te->blockSignals(true);
            cursor.beginEditBlock();
            cursor.removeSelectedText();
            if (!textToAnalyze.isEmpty())
                cursor.insertMarkdown(textToAnalyze);
            cursor.endEditBlock();
            te->blockSignals(false);
        }
        else
            return;
        cursor.setPosition(cachedPosition);
        te->setTextCursor(cursor);
        });
    te->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```